# @IBOutlet и @IBAction в Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift4, storyboard

Очень хотел бы понять что происходит под капотом, когда мы создаем для, например, `UITableView @IBOutlet` (и заодно `@IBAction`) в нашем классе, по умолчанию, в `single view app`, это `ViewController`. Использую XCode 9, Swift 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример для объяснения аналогичный Вашему, но вместо `UITableView` разместил `UIButton` и `UILabel`. Создал для них `IBOutlet` и для кнопки `IBAction`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func someButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

Чтобы посмотреть содержимое `Storyboard`, необходимо в меню выбрать `Open As -> Source Code`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это обычный `xml`. Далее содержимое с пояснениями:

```
<!-- Служебная информация и настройки Interface Builder -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14113" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="Constraints with non-1.0 multipliers" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!-- Сцена определенного контроллераᶦᵐᵃᵍᵉ 
             Помимо контроллера могут содержаться другие элементы. -->
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <!-- Сам UIViewController. 
                     В customClass прописан нужный класс ViewControllerᶦᵐᵃᵍᵉ¹ -->
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="TestOut" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <!-- Элементы, которые добавили на view контроллера -->
                        <subviews>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9pB-MC-br8">
                                <rect key="frame" x="164" y="328.5" width="46" height="30"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                                <!-- Наш IBAction кнопкиᶦᵐᵃᵍᵉ² 
                                     Если удалить в коде, то здесь останется и станет причиной падения приложения.
                                     Поэтому необходимо удалить и здесьᶦᵐᵃᵍᵉ³ -->
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="someButtonAction:" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" eventType="touchUpInside" id="5ZU-Em-zXA"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Yod-no-tEX">
                                <rect key="frame" x="166.5" y="161.5" width="42" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="Yod-no-tEX" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="centerX" id="5va-EN-hGi"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="9pB-MC-br8" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="centerX" id="BK1-nf-Bev"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Yod-no-tEX" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="centerY" multiplier="0.5" id="azM-Ug-DmR"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="9pB-MC-br8" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="centerY" id="fbB-Lb-eko"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                    <!-- Наши IBOutlet. 
                         property - имя IBOutlet переменной в коде.
                         destination - id элемента в storyboard.
                         Ну и по удалению аналогично с IBAction -->
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="someButton" destination="9pB-MC-br8" id="EiS-3u-pbP"/>
                        <outlet property="someLabel" destination="Yod-no-tEX" id="GK0-TO-kgs"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

По сути, `storyboard` является эдаким DI контейнером.

image:

[image: Scene]

image1:

[image: Custom class]

image2:

[image: IBAction]

image3:

[image: Delete IBAction]

image4:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]